# Allowing imported python functions to call other imported python functions

Tags: python, function, import

This is my first time ever importing my own scripts and I have some questions as to how imported functions can interact other with other imported functions. This is what my script currently looks like:

```
from file1 import function1
from file2 import function2

function1()
```

function 1 looks something like this:

```
def function1():
    option = input('Option: ')
    if option == 'function 2':
        function2()
```

and function 2 looks something list this:

```
def function2():
    option = input('Option: ')
    if option = 'function 1':
        function1()
```

Whenever I run this it gives me the error that function2 is not defined. I have tried importing the two scripts within each other but this results in a circular import. My primary purpose for doing this is just to keep the functions of one script better organized, so I am wondering if there is a way to accomplish having two imported functions refer to each other or if I should just forget about it.

Comment: Please share all of the relevant code and the way your project is set up - I'm sure what you need can be done, but it's impossible to tell you what you're doing wrong if you don't tell us what you're doing.

Comment: You seem to assume that python uses something like *dynamic scoping*. It doesn't, it uses *lexical* scope. Your `function1` will try to search for a `function2` available in the scope *where it is defined*, not *where it is called*. If you need `function1` to call `function2`, it has to have access to it, either passed as an argument or available in some scope it can reach (global, enclosing).

Comment: @Grismar I edited the post to include more information

Answer (score 2):

If `function1` invokes `function2`, `function2` must be imported in `file1.py`.

Your project layout should be organized as follows:

*file1.py*

```
from file2 import function2

def function1():
    # function 1 logic
    if condition: 
        function2()
```

*file2.py*

```
def function2():
    # function2 logic
```

*main.py*

```
from file1 import function1

function1()
```

Comment: I apologize I should have clarified in my initial post (now edited) that function 2 referred to function 1 as well as function 1 referring to function 2. Whenever I use this method it then results in a circular import error because both functions import each other.

Comment: Are you sure thats this is the what you want? it may cause a recursive function calls. What are you trying to achieve? maybe there is a better implementation

Comment: So essentially function 1 is a menu with n options and if a certain option is selected it will run a function imported from a different file. All of these functions in turn then refer back to function 1 because they all have the option of returning back to menu. I could include this all in a single file, but I'm trying to learn more about Python as well as complete this project and I also find the extra organization to be quite nice.

Comment: @madamepsychosis then you should put them in the same module.

Comment: I don't see any reason why all those functions have to invoke function1. They **do** have to return value to function1 and this value will be processed afterwards inside function1.